Are maths a form of art?
I came across this idea in the Effective Altruism forum Less Wrong. Here is the link to the post. It says math has the characteristics of an art. But I conjecture something further: that math is nothing more than a form of art.
The idea is that, exactly as one learns to paint, one learns math (by reading or observing). Then, one start painting on his / her own (and mathematician start writing proofs). By art, consider the definition offered by Wikipedia:

Art describes a diverse range of cultural activity centered around works utilizing creative or imaginative talents, which are expected to evoke a worthwhile experience, generally through an expression of emotional power, conceptual ideas, beauty, and/or technical proficiency.

Can we understand others' math proofs, exactly as we can see something of the essence of someone through one of his / her piece of art? Can mathematics be considered a form of art?
Edit:
As Juhasz asked me why I ask this, I'll go and tell my story.
I read 2 or 3 years ago part of the book Principles of Mathematical Analysis from Walter Rudin. Especially I've found chapter 2 on Basic Topology so beautiful that I fell in love with maths and decided to study more maths.
Only now I realize that I've been under the spell of the beauty of the second chapter of this book. And now my goal in my pro life is to teach people how to get skilled in order to one day see the beauty of this book.
I wanted to know from those concerned (mathematicians, namely) if they see the beauty in math too.

Define "art", please.

Edited to try to stave off closure. The interplay between the terms of art and mathematics might elicit some knee-jerk reactions! Feel free to roll back.

Mathematicians often opine that some proofs are "more beautiful" than others, using subjective qualities like "elegance" and "ease of understanding"; that's much like the esthetics of art. And I think there's little doubt that discovering mathematical proofs is a creative process.

In History Of Mathematics Vol I by Eugene Smith, the first section after the introductions is on early art. https://archive.org/details/historyofmathema033304mbp/page/n29/mode/2up. So there is something to math being an art/having artistic roots/being represented by art and vice versa, but I've not come across a philosopher willing to call math whole cloth art...even though as @Barmar said, some of the people most able to see beauty are mathematicians. Part of the reason could be math is often analyzed by analytic philosophy, which doesn't expose itself to art as much.

"art" is a very general term. Is designing cars and buildings an art? Much of it is just functional engineering, but there's an esthetic side to it as well.

Before a truly useful answer could be given to this question, we'd need to know why you're asking it.  Art doesn't have a fixed meaning, it has multiple and fuzzy definitions.  If the question is, could someone come up with a definition of art that includes math, the answer is almost certainly yes.  But what then?  What would you do with that definition?

@Juhasz just wanted to share my thoughts with the community.

An indirect link can be Hacking's notion of style in thinking.

Re to the linked post, I agree that math is not "innate", embedded into our "native" intelligence. It is a skill that we aquire, and different trainings can be more or less efficient to develop our "number sense". But this does not imply that the skill required is the same that an artist aquires.

This question seems to duplicate: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8394/is-mathematics-an-art/8398#8398

Math is in some sense an art, a science, and a form of engineering depending on what your doing. Re art: there are people tastefully constructing beautiful objects and definitions (think Grothendieck) or finding beautiful relationships between known objects (think Ramanujan). Re science: there are folks who are just observing mathematical objects as they are and trying to collect as much data on them as they can (see Experimental math). Re Engineering: There are folks who are using absolute brilliance to modify and strengthen existing machinery to solve impossible problems (think Perelman)

The math community generally rewards Engineering the most. The breakthroughs, the prizes on open problems, the long programs of research towards solving a large collection of problems (ex: Langlands) are all engineering endeavors. In order to engineer well you often have to engage in Science. We generally only accidentally find art in this endeavor, but its impossible to not to appreciate it when we do find. It does seem that some have a knack for uncovering that beauty much more easily than others. One might even argue that art comes after the first blood-spilled paths have been laid first...

...To give a concrete example: you need the Galois's of the world to go to war with their concrete permutation groups before a century later the beautiful abstract notions of "splitting fields", "field extensions", and "automorphism groups" and "group quotients" can happen. The scientists tell us how to walk/that walking is possible. The engineers carve the paths upon we walk. But it's the artists that finally light the candles which allow us to clearly see the rooms we are in. All mathematicians ultimately need to know how to do all three.

Hm, reminds me of that old Star Trek episode "Is there in truth no beauty?"…
If we go back to the Platonic worldview, both math and art are aspects of 'The Good', and so both lean towards the same ideal. And in reality, anything we do well demands a similar combination of structured thought and creativity, be it art of science or math or philosophy. It's just a matter of emphasis.

Any activity can be an art if practiced as an art. Just as any activity can be a meditation if practiced as a meditation.
Others may not recognize it as such. That doesn't make it not art, and doesn't even make it not successful art, since the artist is the one who defines their goals and what constitutes success.
If it doesn't "speak" to a reasonable number of people, or is considered not to be a good example of its type (whatever that is), it may not be widely acclaimed or commercially successful art. But that is a very different question.
As a programmer, I have sometimes described myself as a kinetic poet (by analogy with kinetic sculptor). Much of my work, I admit, is craftsmanship rather than high art. But there have been pieces I think aspire toward the latter, where the fixed and moving parts describe what I consider a particularly elegant pattern.
